# html5 validation with multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, css, html, validation, textbox

```
<input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number"/><input type="hidden" id="card_length"/>
```

if the value of "card_length" is false, then "card_number" should show "invalid card number" as in "html5" custom validity. Please check with multiple textboxes

Comment: but 'card_length' is provided as string..do you want to use it as an object and evaluate it dynamically?

Comment: See i am typing a number in card_number if the number is 10 digit then the card_length will be true, if suppose its false then the card_number should show invalid cardnumber

Comment: ok you already explained the expected behavior, but there is no js code trying to attempt what you wrote, nor html5 properties seeming that you tried any solution. no good.